# "The Application Url cannot contain a query string or fragment" error in asp.net core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

In my `ASP.NET Core 3.1` application, I need to set the query string parameter right from the launch of the application. But when I set an `applicationUrl` having query string parameter in `launchsettings.json` file, application fails to start.

You can see that, the application URL box is turned yellow and Visual Studio does not allow me to save !

[image]

If I open the `launchsettings.json` in the text editor, set this URL and save the file, I get following error while running the application from Visual Studio. I get the following error:

[image]

**Can someone explain,
 1. Why it's not possible?
 2. What's the solution? 
 3. What's ASP.NET Core's way of passing some values during start of the session?**

Note: I need to pass TPAId while launching the application because my app is one of the many other enterprise applications and that's somehow forcing me to do this.

Comment: Just curious, why would you like to add the param right from the start?

Comment: What does that parameter do? Does it, for example, contain database settings? Some user credentials?

Comment: Hi,did your TPAId is unique identifier?If so,you could pass the parameter in Program.cs.

Comment: Every figure anything out?  I have same issue.

Answer (score 7):

In your `launchSettings.json` file, under your Profiles, you can add a `launchUrl` property.

```
"IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "?TPAId=876894",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    }
}
```